# content database SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**please look this first :**

[image: the picture wrong is here]

after make dbhelpercode and DBDatasource and rebuild project and success no bug appear but when make insert this code ( please look the link picture above )

```
db = new DBDataSource(*ContentStudio*.this);
```

the redline says > cannot resolve symbol 'ContentStudio'. trying to fix but no result

**and this DBhelpercode :**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "StudioMusik";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "nama";
public static final String COLUMN_ALAMAT = "alamat";
public static final String COLUMN_HARGA = "harga";
public static final String COLUMN_GAMBAR = "gambar";
public static final String COLUMN_JAMLITE = "jamlite";
public static final String COLUMN_CALLLITE = "call";
public static final String COLUMN_ALATMUSIK = "alatmusik";
public static final String COLUMN_LASTUPDATE = "lastupdate";
public static final String COLUMN_RATINGALAT = "ratingalat";
public static final String COLUMN_RATINGRECORDING = "ratingrecording";
public static final String COLUMN_RATINGTEMPAT = "ratingtempat";
public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

private static final String db_name ="studioivan.db";
private static final int db_version=1;
private static final String db_create = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + COLUMN_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_NAME+ " varchar(50) not null, "
        + COLUMN_ALAMAT+ " varchar(50) not null, "
        + COLUMN_HARGA + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_GAMBAR + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_JAMLITE + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_CALLLITE + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_ALATMUSIK + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_LASTUPDATE + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_RATINGALAT + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_RATINGRECORDING + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_RATINGTEMPAT + " varchar(50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " varchar (50) not null,"
        + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " varchar (50) not null);";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
    // Auto generated
}

//mengeksekusi perintah SQL di atas untuk membuat tabel database baru
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(db_create);
}

// dijalankan apabila ingin mengupgrade database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}}
```

**and this DBDatasource :**

```
public class DBDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private DBHelper dbHelper;

private String[] allColumns = { DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_ALAMAT, DBHelper.COLUMN_HARGA, DBHelper.COLUMN_GAMBAR,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_JAMLITE,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_CALLLITE,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_ALATMUSIK,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_LASTUPDATE,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGALAT,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGRECORDING,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGTEMPAT,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE
};

public DBDataSource(Context context)
{
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

// Insert data
public boolean insertStudioMusik(String id, String nama, String alamat, String harga, String gambar,
                                 String jam,
                                 String call,
                                 String alatmusik,
                                 String lastupdate,
                                 String ratingalat,
                                 String ratingrecording,
                                 String ratingtempat,
                                 String latitude,
                                 String longitude) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, id);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, nama);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ALAMAT, alamat);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_HARGA, harga);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_GAMBAR, gambar);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_JAMLITE, jam);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_CALLLITE, call);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ALATMUSIK, alatmusik);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LASTUPDATE, lastupdate);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGALAT, ratingalat);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGRECORDING, ratingrecording);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGTEMPAT, ratingtempat);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);

    long insertId = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,
            values);

    if (insertId == -1) return false;
    else return true;
}

//set data
private StudioMusik cursorToStudioMusik(Cursor cursor)
{
    StudioMusik studiomusik = new StudioMusik();
    // debug LOGCAT
    studiomusik.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    studiomusik.setNama(cursor.getString(1));
    studiomusik.setAlamat(cursor.getString(2));
    studiomusik.setHarga(cursor.getString(3));
    studiomusik.setGambar(cursor.getString(4));
    studiomusik.setJam(cursor.getString(5));
    studiomusik.setCall(cursor.getString(6));
    studiomusik.setAlatmusik(cursor.getString(7));
    studiomusik.setLastupdate(cursor.getString(8));
    studiomusik.setRatingalat(cursor.getString(9));
    studiomusik.setRatingrecording(cursor.getString(10));
    studiomusik.setRatingtempat(cursor.getString(11));
    studiomusik.setLatitude(cursor.getString(12));
    studiomusik.setLongitude(cursor.getString(13));

    return studiomusik;
}

//mengambil semua data StudioMusik
public ArrayList<StudioMusik> getStudioMusik() {
    ArrayList<StudioMusik> daftarStudioMusik = new ArrayList<StudioMusik>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    // pindah ke data paling pertama
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // jika masih ada data, masukkan data barang ke
    // daftar barang
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        StudioMusik studioMusik = cursorToStudioMusik(cursor);
        daftarStudioMusik.add(studioMusik);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return daftarStudioMusik;
}


//ambil satu barang sesuai id
public boolean isFavorite(Integer id)
{
    StudioMusik studiomusik = new StudioMusik();
    //select query
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, "_id ="+id,null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) return true;
    else return false;
}

//update studio yang diedit
public void updateStudioMusik(StudioMusik b)
{
    //ambil id barang
    String strFilter = "_id=" + b.getId();
    //memasukkan ke content values
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    //masukkan data sesuai dengan kolom pada database
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, b.getNama());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ALAMAT, b.getAlamat());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_HARGA, b.getHarga());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_GAMBAR, b.getGambar());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_JAMLITE, b.getJam());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_CALLLITE, b.getCall());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ALATMUSIK, b.getAlatmusik());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LASTUPDATE, b.getLastupdate());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGALAT, b.getRatingalat());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGRECORDING, b.getRatingrecording());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATINGTEMPAT, b.getRatingtempat());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, b.getLatitude());
    args.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, b.getLongitude());

    //update query
    database.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, args, strFilter, null);
}

// delete studio sesuai ID
public void deleteStudioMusik(Integer id)
{
    String strFilter = "_id=" + id;
    database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, strFilter, null);
}}
```

**anyone can tell me where is the problem? or the where codes should be fix?
thank you ( sry my bad english )**

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` instead.

```
db = new DBDataSource(this);
```

Comment: @Arizal Did you try my answer? Have you solved the issue?

Comment: iam sry for late answer, to be honest when rebuild or sync no bug anymore but no yet try to build apk and test it in smartphone